# Tag diffing in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, diff

In mercurial is there a way to diff between 2 different tags?

I have tagged my builds and have a couple commits in between builds and want to figure out the differences between the 2 builds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
hg diff -r tag1:tag2
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Don't type the dollars :-). Example: hg diff -r 2.2.3:2.2.4

Comment: This doesn't work for me yet, because it includes the last changeset that went into the earlier build.  The changeset tagged with tag1 seems like something you don't want in the list right?  Is there a best practice that you have to make empty changesets for your builds and then put the tags on the empty changesets?  That might make it work, but I haven't seen that discussed anyplace yet.

Answer (score 6):

This [answer in the Kiln StackExchange](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/656/how-do-i-find-the-list-of-files-that-changed-since-a-named-tag) seems quite complete (based on [`hg diff`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Diff) and hg log):

> To see all of the changesets that were introduced between, say, the tags v1.0 and v1.1, run:

```
hg log -r v1.0:v1.1
```

> To see the net sum of differences introduced in those revisions, you'd instead run:

```
hg diff -r v1.0:v1.1
```

> Mercurial can even format this output in changelog-style, if you want. Simply add the `--style changelog` parameter:

```
hg log -r v1.0:v1.1 --style changelog
```